# IBM Datastage - input file metadata

Tags: websphere, netezza, datastage, ibm-infosphere

We have multpile DataStage jobs that input flat files. Is there a quick way to find what job uses specific 'file.csv'? I'm looking for some kind of search bar within DataStage or Governance Catalogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advanced find function in Designer Client can search for object types and for text in object descriptions, but it does not search property values and in this case file.csv would be value of the File property in the Sequential File stage.   I cannot say whether Governance Catalog would be able to search the property values or not.

One method that you can use would be to use DataStage Director client to export the jobs in project to a dsx file.  You can then search the dsx file for occurrences of "file.csv".  Wherever you find a match in the dsx file, then search backward to the prior "BEGIN DSJOB" string, and that will start the job definition, followed immediately by job name, i.e.:
BEGIN DSJOB
Identifier "testfile_job"    (this is the job name).

If you need to know which folder the job is in, that is shown on the Category line that occurs between BEGIN DSJOB and END DSJOB.

Thanks.